# print even and odd numbers

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

now my code looks like this

```
!/bin/bash

read INPUT
for number in $(seq 1 $INPUT); do
        if [ $((number%2)) -eq 0 ]
        else [ $((number%2)) -eq 1 ]; then
           echo $number
        fi
done
```

but then I get the next error

```
./script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./script.sh: line 6: `        else [ $((number%2)) -eq 1 ]; then'
```

Comment: Use another loop that use `-ne` instead of `-eq`

Comment: Or use `-eq 1`.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit the question to show what you tried, and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `print even numbers, how do i print odd numbers aswell?` Print all numbers, just `seq 1 $INPUT` prints all numbers.

Comment: Take a look at `help if`.

Comment: https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Your first if needs a ;then and your else needs an elif .. but honestly you need to rework it all anyway...

Comment: @omer be sure to upvote answers etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `then` statement after `if`.

You can set a variable to the parity of the input number. Then you can use that variable when testing each number in the range.

```
#!/bin/bash

read INPUT
parity=$((INPUT%2))
for number in $(seq 1 $INPUT); do
    if [ $((number%2)) -eq $parity ]; then
       echo $number
    fi
done
```

Comment: I want the code to show me only even numbers when I write 10 
EX: 
2,4,6,8,10
and odd number when I write 9 
1,3,5,7,9

Comment: Why doesn't it say that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read INPUT
str=""
for each in $(seq 1 $INPUT); do
    [[ $((each%2)) -eq 0 ]] && str="$str $each"
done
echo $str
```

What this is doing is performing the check in an if statement $(()) and the && means if true that do the follwowing which is to build a string as we go of the ones that meet our criteria.

Example:

```
14
2 4 6 8 10 12 14
```